# implement sort of @can for a set of users that include unauthorized users

Tags: php, laravel

I'm writing a suggestion (or idea) application. Logic is simple, only logged-in users can post ideas, but anybody can see ideas (think like StackOverflow questions), every idea has a state:

- editing
- posted
- in evaluation
- implemented
- rejected

and so on, so not every user can see every state. For example, only the author can see an idea in `editing` state, and nobody should see an idea before it is `accepted`.

So I thought it would be too easy to implement with policies and can like:

```php
public function view(User $user, Idea $idea)
{
    if ($user->id === $idea->user_id) return true;

    return $idea->state->visible;
}
```

and...

```html
@can('view', $idea)
        ...
@endcan
```

Every state has a `visible` columns that means "visible for everyone" when `true`, and "visible for author" when `false`. Problem is, `@can` only works for signed users.

I don't feel like writting the display logic inside an `@if` (if user is author OR state is visible), it works without problems tho...

Even worse, I don't like to write an accessor like `public function getVisibleAttribute()` in the `Idea` model

So... what are my options? which is the *correct* way?

My problem is already solved, but I think it's quite... *dirty* (I used the `@if`).

EDIT: ---------------------------

Let me show how horrid my solution is:

```
@php $ok = false; @endphp
@auth
    @php $ok = Auth::user()->id === $idea->user_id; @endphp
@endauth
@if (($idea->state->visible) || ($ok))
    <!-- Display record -->
@endif
```

The `$ok` thing is necessary because if I ask for `Auth::user()->id` it gives me the asking for id of null error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I didn't like my horrid answer, I just did second option, at least is a bit cleaner, but I still don't like it.

I created an accessor in the `Idea` model:

```
public function getIsVisibleAttribute()
{
  if (Auth::guest()) return $this->estado->vis;

  return ($this->estado->vis) || (Auth::user()->id === $this->user_id);
}
```

And then is used in the blade file:

```
@if ($idea->isVisible)
    <!-- Display idea -->
@endif
```

I still think the rule doesn't belong here

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
public function view(User $user, Idea $idea)
{
    if ($user->id === $idea->user_id || $idea->state->visible){
         return true;
     }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: I think it won't work, `@can` and policies apply only for authorized (logged-in users), and it makes sense... so, fot unauthorized users `@can` is always false